# Boggling googling

Tags: riddle, calculation-puzzle, computer-puzzle

> I'm a number for you to evaluate,
>   Googling 'me' gives the drop off the Empire State,
>   Though the great Google finds no results for me,
>   I'm just a pure integer value you'll see.

**What number am I?**

*The Empire State building is 381 m tall (to the roof).

Comment: Unfortunately, where I currently am, Google is blocked!

Comment: Doesn't evaluation of a number requires a tag of 'calculation' /'mathematics'  ?

Comment: Using the fact given in the question (with measurement knowledge) would need basic calculation, so the tag would fit. Using search engines, only counting or trial is needed.

Comment: If this actually involves googling, it may be worth noting that Google can show different results on different occasions to different people, so unless it's perfectly consistent in this case the riddle may be literally insoluble. (Of course that's assuming we should take the stuff about Google results at face value, which isn't a given.)

Comment: The core of this puzzle is Google specific. From another SE site I think this is universal.

Comment: I added the computer-puzzle tag now . Also please take this puzz at face value.

Comment: it's . . . interesting . . . that 1250 feet is *exactly* 381 meters, and 381 meters is *exactly* 1250 feet.  I'm not expressing this well, but I was surprised I didn't get a decimal *somewhere* when I made the conversion . . . I suppose this is just rounding error . . .

Comment: @R.Dye, correct observation which would be good to add as an explanation for line 4 - I'm impressed that you checked the conversion  both ways :). For say line 3 next just think of what numbers are ungooglable.

Comment: Well . . . you *can* google both "nothing" and "infinity," but in another way, you *can't . . .*. Other than that, I got nothing. ;-)

Comment: "Phone numbers" supposedly can no longer be googled, but this is only partially true. . . I tried googling the "drop off point for the Empire State Building," and that gives a phone number.  Googling that phone number gives the Empire State Building, but not the height, and not the address ("drop off point".

Comment: Interesting point about phone numbers. The answer is just an integer (written in most common way) and will have no (zero) results when input in the Google search box. This actually happened to me at work on Friday and is same for colleagues I've checked with in different places, though i changed the number to get the play on units and the Empire State fits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> -1251

Because Google has a kind of quirk with interpreting

> single quotes as "feet", and the search for '-1251' is interpreted as "foot -(1251 feet)" = -1250 feet, which is the drop off the ESB.

Also, Google finds no results for you because the

> minus sign in -1251 negates the search term.

As for the rest of the hints,

> OP's intended answer for the last line was the exact conversion 381 m = 1250 ft

Answer (score 1):

YOU ARE:

> either 1 or 50 depending which side of the ocean you're on.

I'm a number for you to evaluate,

> You are a number!

Googling 'me' gives the drop off the Empire State,

> There is an old saying... dropping a 50c (AUD) or 1c (UDS) piece of metal will do certain things upon impact.

Though the great Google finds no results for me,

> This a red herring on the line "Googling 'me'"

I'm just a pure integer value you'll see.

> I'm not sure about just but indeed 50 and 1 are indeed integers.

Comment: There're no herring in this! I'm afraid the riddle tag may be misleading (applied more for form than function) and there is no cryptic/lateral thinking/word play involved. I would say I'm certain there are nil google results for line 3, and that line 2 will work for the overwhelming majority, especially in English (though also Brasil/Deutsch/Indonesia/.. - although didn't for me in.Setswana).